# Ashkenazic and Sephardic tefillin

Tags: minhag, tefilin, ashkenazi, sephardim, orach-chaim

There are tefillin shel yad where the handle is on one side of the box and the knot is on the other, and there are also tefillin shel had where the handle and the knot are on the same side of the box. Which is Ashkenazi, and which is Sephardic? Does it depend which type of Ashkenazi or Sephardic community?

Comment: usually, temani and ashkenazi (not chasidim) have the loop on the same side as the knot